# adding if statements to a function returning an error

Tags: r

This is a follow on post to one I posted earlier. The code is the following:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(Species = +(Species == "virginica")) %>% 
  sample_n(10)

##########################################
var_combos <- expand.grid(colnames(df[,1:4]), colnames(df[,1:4])) %>% 
  filter(!Var1 == Var2)

boundary_lists <- map2(
  .x = var_combos$Var1,
  .y = var_combos$Var2,
  ~select(df, .x, .y) %>% 
    summarise(
      minX = min(.[[1]], na.rm = TRUE),
      maxX = max(.[[1]], na.rm = TRUE),
      minY = min(.[[2]], na.rm = TRUE),
      maxY = max(.[[2]], na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  ) %>% 
  map(.,
      ~tibble(
        x = seq(.x$minX, .x$maxX, length.out = 200),
        y = seq(.x$minY, .x$maxY, length.out = 200),
        )
      ) %>% 
  map(.,
      ~tibble(
        xx = rep(.x$x, each = 200),
        yy = rep(.x$y, time = 200)
        )
      ) %>% 
  map2(.,
       asplit(var_combos, 1), ~ .x %>% 
         set_names(.y))


# xgboost(
#   objective='binary:logistic',
#   eval_metric = 'auc',
#   data = as.matrix(df[, 1:2]),
#   label = as.matrix(df[, 5]), # binary variable
#   nrounds = 10
#   )

models_list <- map2(
  var_combos$Var1,
  var_combos$Var2,
  ~df %>%
    select(Species, .x, .y) %>%
    group_by(grp = 'grp') %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      models = map(
        data, 
        ~{
          list(
            glm(Species ~ ., data = .x, family = binomial(link='logit')),
            e1071::svm(Species ~ ., data = .x,  type = 'C-classification', kernel = 'linear'),
            randomForest::randomForest(formula = as.factor(Species) ~ ., data = .),
            xgboost(
              objective='binary:logistic',
              eval_metric = 'auc',
              data = as.matrix(.x[, 2:3]),
              label = as.matrix(.x$Species), # binary variable
              nrounds = 10
            )
          )
        }
      )
    )
) %>% 
  map(
    ., ~unlist(., recursive = FALSE)
  )
```

This works but I am trying to expand it to take on more models with some changes to the `predict` function.

I would like to create a new `predict` function and `tibble` for each model I train on where I can modify the data inside each of the `~if` statements. The code I have is:

```
    map2_dfr(models_list, boundary_lists, ~{
  mods <- pluck(.x, "models")
  dat <- .y
  map_dfr(mods,

          ~if(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "glm"){              # predict the logistic model
            tibble(
              modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1],
              prediction = predict(.x, newdata = dat)
              )
          }

          ~if(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "svm.formula"){      # predict the SVM model
            tibble(
              modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1],
              prediction = predict(.x, newdata = dat)
              )
          }

          ~if(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "randomForest.formula"){   # predict the RF model
            tibble(
              modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1],
              prediction = predict(.x, newdata = dat)
              )
          }

          ~if(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "xgb.Booster"){       # predict the XGBoost model
            tibble(
              modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1], 
              prediction = predict(.x, newdata = as.matrix(dat), type = 'prob')
              ) 
          }
      #else {
      #  tibble(modelname = attr(.x, "class")[1],
      #         prediction = predict(.x, newdata = dat))}   )   

  )
  }
  )
```

Which is giving me the error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   )
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"
```

I cannot seem to find where the unexpected part of the code is. I "assume" there is a problem with me passing the `~if` statements. How can I pass multiple `if` statements in this mannor?

Comment: I think you need `else if` and finally just `else` instead of serial `if`s after that initial one.

Comment: Yeha, you seem to just have these floating `~if` statements. You should have just one `~` in the `map_dfr` to define the function. Combine those statements into one statement.

Comment: Thanks, I see your points. Is there a function such as `when`. That is `when(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "glm"){...` - do this..., `when(attr(.x, "class")[1] == "svm.formula"){...` - do that.... Where I want to explicitly state the criteria and tell the function what to do when that criteria is met? or is this against best practices?

Comment: @user113156 check out `switch`. You can see what it does by doing `f <- function(x) switch(class(x), numeric = print(rnorm(5)), character = print(sample(letters, 5)))` and then trying `f(1)` and `f("hello")`

Comment: Changing the `~if` commands to `else if` gives the error: `Error: No common type for `..1$prediction` <double> and `..2$prediction` <factor<dec08>>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method which works :

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- map2_df(models_list, boundary_lists, ~{
    mods <- purrr::pluck(.x, "models")
    dat <- .y
    map_df(mods, function(x)
      tryCatch({
          if(attr(x, "class")[1] == "glm"){   
           # predict the logistic model
            tibble(
              modelname = attr(x, "class")[1],
              prediction = predict(x, newdata = dat)
             )
            }    
          else if(attr(x, "class")[1] == "svm.formula"){ 
               # predict the SVM model
            tibble(
              modelname = attr(x, "class")[1],
              prediction = as.numeric(as.character(predict(x, newdata = dat)))
             )
            }
          else if(attr(x, "class")[1] == "randomForest.formula"){  
               # predict the RF model
            tibble(
             modelname = attr(x, "class")[1],
             prediction = as.numeric(as.character(predict(x, newdata = dat)))
            )
          }    
          else if(attr(x, "class")[1] == "xgb.Booster"){      
               # predict the XGBoost model
            tibble(
             modelname = attr(x, "class")[1], 
             prediction = predict(x, newdata = as.matrix(dat), type = 'prob')
            ) 
          }
       }, error = function(e) { print('skipping\n')})
      )
 })
```

The changes which I did are :

- Used `~` only once at the beginning of the function and not for every `if`
- Since this is a nested `map`, using `.x` can create confusion about what it refers to. Hence, used an anonymous function in the inside `map_df` block so arguments of `map2_df` are referred with `.x` and `.y` and arguments of `map_df` are referred with `x`.
- Some models return predicted variable as `factors`, hence wrapping `as.numeric(as.character())` around them.
- Added `tryCatch` for better handling of exceptions.